# Correct way to protect against failed memory allocations using new operator and 2D Array

Tags: c++, memory-management

In the code below is the initial first loop needed when creating a 2D array, or if there is a failed memory allocation will the pointers to the actual rows be initialized to NULL?

```
unsigned char **row_pointers;
try
{
  row_pointers = new unsigned char *[height];
  for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    row_pointers[i] = NULL;
  for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    row_pointers[i] = new unsigned char[width];
}
catch (std::bad_alloc)
{
  throw std::runtime_error("Failure to allocate memory for raw data");
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

To clarify, the code I am looking at is:

```
149   /*
150    * Allocate sufficient space for the data
151    */
152   unsigned char **row_pointers;
153   try
154   {
155     row_pointers = new unsigned char *[height]();
156     for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
157       row_pointers[i] = new unsigned char[width];
158   }   
159   catch (std::bad_alloc)
160   {
161     /*
162      * If insufficient memory than try and clean up
163      * and throw runtime error
164      */ 
165     for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
166     { 
167       if (row_pointers[i] != NULL)
168       { 
169         delete row_pointers[i];
170       }
171     }
172     throw std::runtime_error("Failure to allocate raw memory for data");
173   }
...   // White Space
177 
178   /*
179    * Now read the data all at once (no need to handle interlacing
180    */
181   png_read_image(m_pPNG, row_pointers);
182 
183   for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
184   {
185     for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
186       std::cout << row_pointers[i][j];
187     std::cout << std::endl;
188   }
```

Comment: `std::vector` would be a simpler solution to this.

Comment: Using with libpng, not an option

Comment: @MatthewHoggan I'm not familiar with `libpng`, but unless that library is taking ownership of the memory you are allocating you almost certainly can avoid manual memory management.  Show _where_ you are using this construct (what `libpng` function is involved), and I bet we can find a way to do it better.

Comment: The loops look wrong: `for (int i = 0; i < 0; ++i)` - should be `height` instead of `0`

Comment: Also, `new unsigned char *[height]()` (with parentheses) will initialize pointers to NULL

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the typo anatolyg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array allocated with `new unsigned char*[height]` is not initialized by this operation. If any allocation fails it will throw an exception. In your code you next initialize you array. I think this should look like this:

```
std::fill_n(row_pointers, height, 0);
```

Of course, if any subsequent allocation fails this array will be leaked as will all the other arrays allocated so far. You could clean this mess up in the `catch`-block.

Personally, I cannot cope with multiple clean-ups: it is just too complicated to get right. Personally I would use two `std::vector<T>` instead, bundled into a class:

- one `std::vector<unsigned char*>` which gets initialized to point to the start of the subvectors
- one `std::vector<unsigned char>` to hold all of the subvectors

Once these are allocated, the pointers in the first vector are set up to point into the second vector at appropriate locations. Conveniently, if anything goes wrong the destructors of the two vectors will take care of the clean-up.

Here is how this would look like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

struct array2d
{
    array2d(std::size_t height, std::size_t width)
        : inner_(height * width)
        , outer_(height)
    {
        for (std::size_t i(0); i != height; ++i) {
            this->outer_[i] = &this->inner_[i * width];
        }
    }

    unsigned char** get() { return &this->outer_[0]; }

    std::vector<unsigned char> inner_;
    std::vector<unsigned char*> outer_;
};
```

When you got an object `picture` of this type you could use `picture.get()` to get pointer suitable to be passed to C functions.

Comment: [Boost Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html)

Comment: This is great advice and I understand that with the std::vector class you get RAII handled for you. However, in my commend above I pointed out that I am interfacing with a C library, libpng which make using a vector a bit difficult. If I am wrong please correct.

Comment: You don't need to disclose the `std::vector<unsigned char*>` to the C library: `&vec[0]` in a non-empty vector yields a pointer to the first element. I think C++ 2011 adds a `data()` method to do the same with a nicer notation. I don't see any reason why this can't be used with C APIs.

Comment: row pointers must be a 2D array that is a vector<vector<bytes> >. But you would have to pass in the first vector to png_read_image unless you do a sequential read, which I don't want to do because it requires c functions and callbacks which really mirks things up.

Comment: No, that is not a requirement. I added a code example to show what I mean: you would get a `unsigned char**` out of it although it internally uses two vectors (not `height + 1` vectors).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the compiler and options, but to be safe you should keep the initialization if you expect it.

Some compilers with the debug option will initialize the `row_pointers` array with 0 values.  Others will fill it with markers (like `0xcc`) and others will just leave it uninitialized.

I'm not sure, but I think there might also be options that would return NULL instead of throwing `std::bad_alloc` in which case the extra initialization would be unnecessary.

When in doubt, however, be explicit!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good reading for you:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20new/

Answer (score -2):

Which OS are you compiling for? With some (e.g. linux) new will never fail, instead you will get a segment violation later when you use the memory!

In this scenario you would trigger the segment violation during the first initialisation loop.

It might be a good time to read some of Herb Sutters GOTW

see: [GOTW - To New, Perchance To Throw, Part 2](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill16.htm)

Note: After newing either dimension you could use `memset` to initialise the data, ergo the first loop could be replace by `memset( row_pointers, sizeof(unsigned char *)*height, 0 )`.

Comment: No reasons for downvote given … the only reason I could imagine is the blanket statement “Linux” which, as far as I know, isn’t always correct. But in general this answer is indeed correct.

Comment: I've never heard of an implementation where `new` would behave as he described, and even if there are some, those are not conforming C++ compilers.  In fact, I would call that useless.  That would be impossible to write a safe program in.

Comment: @Mooing Duck - Note: I added the link to gotw which explains this behaviour in detail. I am currently developing an embedded Linux application for ARM 9 processors. Some stress testing consumed all memory - the assert calls did not fail, instead the program exited with Sigsev when the memory was written to!

Comment: @mark: downvote retracted, but I don't think the article isn't entirely correct.  Even on linux I'm pretty sure `new` can fail if it runs out of virtual memory.

Comment: Why does this keep getting down voted without any explanation? Are the down voters incapable of reading the link supplied?